# How to Install SSL certificate from goDaddy in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ssl

I have a certificate bought from godaddy and it needs to be installed in our nodejs server.I have the below code written. This was working earlier but we recently renewed the certificate and replaced the old certificates with the renewed certificate and certificate private key file in the specified folder. But the certificate information is not getting reflected in the website. The expiry date for old certificate was june-20,2018.Will it not reflect till the old one gets expired?

```
var options = {
   key: fs.readFileSync('certificate/mssp.tcs.com.key'),
   cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate/mssp.tcs.com.crt'),
  ca: [fs.readFileSync('certificate/mssp.tcs.comi.crt')]

};

var server = app.listen(8001, function () {
    console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
    console.log("server Started");
});

https.createServer(options,app).listen('443 ');
```

Comment: Browsers cache SSL certificates. Try with a different browser or another system that has never been to your site.

Comment: @JohnHanley Browsers will use the certificates send by servers when they start the handshake.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - I have seen ssl caching issues with Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are importing the certificate and key is correct. So I think your issue is probably caused by pointing to the old files or existing process using old certificates. In this situation I suggest:

1. Double check `certificate/mssp.tcs.com.*` files to ensure all of them are really pointing to the renewed files. Sometimes we have symbolic links to restricted folders and a simple copy might fail without correct privileges.
2. Once you ensure that new files are in place. Make sure you `kill` the older process that might be running. You can achieve that by a `ps -ef | grep node` on linux servers and then `kill` it by PID. Just be careful to stop the correct application. Once you stop the old process, you should get a 'Not Found' if you access your web application through a browser.
3. Ensuring you have new files in place and that old process is not running anymore, start your node process. Your certificates should be updated :)

Finally, I would also suggest you to review the `server` which is running on port 8001 without https. Just make sure you need that or remove it. A simple code to run HTTPS can be like that:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    https = require('https');

var httpPort = 443;   
var app = express();    
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

app.set('port', httpPort);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

https.createServer(options, app).listen(httpPort, function(){
    console.log('Listening at ' +  httpPort);
});
```